# How to make event stop propagating in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

First off I did look at all the related answers but none solved my problem.  I have the following:

```
class TweetingBox extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div id="page-blackout" onClick={this.props.closeTweetingInterface}>
                <div id="tweeting-box" onClick={(proxy) => {proxy.stopPropogation()}}>
                    <h5 id="tweeting-box-header">Compose new Tweet</h5>
                    <TweetingInterface initialContent={this.props.initialContent}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

div with `id="page-blackout"` covers the entire page and div with `id="tweeting-box"` is centered on the page, containing a form in the component `TweetingInterface`.  When I click anywhere, both in the form as well as on tweeting-box itself, `this.props.closeTweetingInterface` is called.  How can I stop this?

Comment: It might be that `page-blackout` is on top of the `tweeting-box` so you actually click overlay? Otherwise your approach with `stopPropogation` is correct and should work.

Comment: I think your approach is correct, you just have a spelling error. It should be `proxy.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 0):

All the sibling elements will get their parents property, so the parent function will get called closeTweetingInterface every time the parent or the sibling elements get called on.

Comment: so how do I get my desired outcome here?

Comment: you can have a parent element and in that parent element you can have to sibling elements the first can be cross icon or something on which you click and it executes closeTweetingInterface function and the other sibling element which is tweeting box can have onClick={(proxy) => {proxy.stopPropogation()}}